# Encontrar palavras em uma string

Tags: php, string

Estou criando uma função em PHP que recebe uma `string`. Em seguida, ele deve procurar, dentro dessa `string`, palavras dentro de colchetes e salva-las em um array.

Existe alguma função que realize a busca apenas dessas palavras e salve-as em um array? Ou em uma variável para depois eu passasse ela para um array?

Exemplo da string:

```
 <font color="maroon">[como]</font>  &lt;rel&gt; &lt;ks&gt; <font color="blue"><b>ADV</b> </font> <font color="darkgreen">@ADVL&gt;</font> <font color="darkgreen"><b>@#FS-ADVL</font></b> <font color="darkgreen"><b>@#FS-N&lt;</font></b>
    <dt><b><font color="maroon">não</font></b> 

    <font color="maroon">[não]</font>  <font color="blue"><b>ADV</b> </font> <font color="darkgreen">@ADVL&gt;</font>
    <dt><b><font color="maroon">amar</font></b> 

    <font color="maroon">[amar]</font>  &lt;vt&gt; <font color="blue"><b>V</b> FUT 1/3S SUBJ VFIN </font> <font color="darkgreen">@FMV</font>
    <dt><b><font color="maroon">uma</font></b> 

    <font color="maroon">[um]</font>  &lt;arti&gt; <font color="blue"><b>DET</b> F S </font> <font color="darkgreen">@&gt;N</font>
    <dt><b><font color="maroon">pessoa</font></b> 

    <font color="maroon">[pessoa]</font>  &lt;H&gt; <font color="blue"><b>N</b> F S </font> <font color="darkgreen">@&lt;ACC</font>
    <dt><b><font color="maroon">tão</font></b> 

    <font color="maroon">[tão]</font>  &lt;dem&gt; &lt;quant&gt; <font color="blue"><b>ADV</b> </font> <font color="darkgreen">@&gt;A</font>
    <dt><b><font color="maroon">linda</font></b> 

    <font color="maroon">[lindo]</font>  <font color="blue"><b>ADJ</b> F S </font> <font color="darkgreen">@N&lt;</font>
    <dt><b><font color="maroon">.</font></b>
```

exemplo do array

```
Array
(
    [0] => como
    [1] => não
    [2] => amar
    [3] => um
    [5] => pessoa
    [6] => tão
    [7] => lindo

)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode usar um expressão regular, para capturar somente os caracteres entre os colchetes, o único detalhe é escapa-los já que eles são metacaracteres.

A expressão é `\[.*\]/`, significa capture um abre colchetes seguido de qualquer caracter o maior número de vezes e obrigatoriamente deve parar ao encontar um fecha colchetes.

```
<?php
$str = '
<font color="maroon">[como]</font>  &lt;rel&gt; &lt;ks&gt; <font color="blue"><b>ADV</b> </font> <font color="darkgreen">@ADVL&gt;</font> <font color="darkgreen"><b>@#FS-ADVL</font></b> <font color="darkgreen"><b>@#FS-N&lt;</font></b>
    <dt><b><font color="maroon">não</font></b> 

    <font color="maroon">[não]</font>  <font color="blue"><b>ADV</b> </font> <font color="darkgreen">@ADVL&gt;</font>
    <dt><b><font color="maroon">amar</font></b> 

    <font color="maroon">[amar]</font>  &lt;vt&gt; <font color="blue"><b>V</b> FUT 1/3S SUBJ VFIN </font> <font color="darkgreen">@FMV</font>
    <dt><b><font color="maroon">uma</font></b> 

    <font color="maroon">[um]</font>  &lt;arti&gt; <font color="blue"><b>DET</b> F S </font> <font color="darkgreen">@&gt;N</font>
    <dt><b><font color="maroon">pessoa</font></b> 

    <font color="maroon">[pessoa]</font>  &lt;H&gt; <font color="blue"><b>N</b> F S </font> <font color="darkgreen">@&lt;ACC</font>
    <dt><b><font color="maroon">tão</font></b> 

    <font color="maroon">[tão]</font>  &lt;dem&gt; &lt;quant&gt; <font color="blue"><b>ADV</b> </font> <font color="darkgreen">@&gt;A</font>
    <dt><b><font color="maroon">linda</font></b> 

    <font color="maroon">[lindo]</font>  <font color="blue"><b>ADJ</b> F S </font> <font color="darkgreen">@N&lt;</font>
    <dt><b><font color="maroon">.</font></b>';

$regex ='/\[.*\]/';
preg_match_all($regex, $str, $matches);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($matches);
```

[Exemplo - ideone](http://ideone.com/sQyykS)